# Where the built file of NativePHP

Tags: php, laravel, native-php

I am using the NativePHP package to build my application, after I complete the developing process, I need to export the file to be a desktop application.

So, I run this command:

```
php artisan native:build
```

I got this result from the Ubuntu Linux Terminal

[image]

So, where I can get the file of the execution file to share it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), use text instead, e.g. a code block. And have you tried looking this up the manual? Albeit it is alpha grade software, you might get some valuable pointers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Shane D Rosenthal](https://laravel-news.com/@ShaneDRosenthal) in *[NativePHP Tutorial: Building a Mac MenuBar application](https://laravel-news.com/nativephp-tutorial)* (July 31st, 2023; for [Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/)):

> ```
> php artisan native:build
> ```
>
> Running this command [...]. Once complete, the files will be placed in your project's `root/dist` directory and you can distribute the app as you see fit.

The original docs seem a bit thin yet for that command, only what it is for, but not what the build goals are. (*[ref](https://nativephp.com/docs/1/publishing/building#running-a-build)*)

It's perhaps not yet set in stone.